I can't understand machine epsilon arithmetic
I know that arithmetic operations whose result is close to zero can sometimes be non-associative. This follows directly from the definition of machine epsilon. however, I decided to test another equality with it and got some unexpected results.
//just calculate
float epsilon_float = 1.0f;
auto counter_float = 0;
while ((epsilon_float / 2 + 1.0f) != 1.0f) {
    epsilon_float /= 2;
    counter_float += 1;
}

std::cout << (1 < 1 + epsilon_float) << std::endl;
std::cout << (1 == 1 + epsilon_float / 2) << std::endl;   
std::cout << (1 + epsilon_float > 1 + epsilon_float / 2) << std::endl;  // By definition

std::cout << (1 + epsilon_float + epsilon_float / 2 >
              1 + epsilon_float / 2 + epsilon_float) << std::endl;    // Non-associativity


std::cout << (1 + epsilon_float < 1 + epsilon_float + epsilon_float / 2)  // its true
        << std::endl;

I can’t understand why the second part of the inequality turns out to be greater than the first, because, as far as I understand, machine epsilon is the minimum number that, when added to one, gives a non-one result. But here eps/2 adds up to a number greater than one

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Machine epsilon confuses lots of people not least because denormalised numbers are smaller still (but much slower) and can affect some computations. BTW An MRE should compile without errors - it is missing obvious include files as written. You might find it enlightening to feed your code into Godbolt to see what code is actually being generated - then you can experiment with brackets to force the order of computation you intend.

Re “machine epsilon is the minimum number that, when added to one, gives a non-one result”: That is not a correct definition of the epsilon. The so-called epsilon is the different between 1 and the next representable number. Consider 1 and the next representable value after it, 1+u. (“u” for unit of least precision, called ULP.) The epsilon is the difference between these two numbers, (1+u) − 1 = u. However, if we take 1 and add some other number to it, then the floating-point operation applies rounding to produce a representable result. This rounding changes the number we get…

… And that means you cannot use floating-point addition as a basis for defining machine epsilon. When you take 1 and add u/2, the real-number-arithmetic result, 1+u/2, is not representable, because there are no representable numbers between 1 and 1+u. A floating-point addition rounds the result. Instead of producing 1+u/2, which is impossible, it rounds up to produce 1+u. So the “machine epsilon” is not the smallest number that added to 1, produces a number greater than 1.

Re “I know that arithmetic operations whose result is close to zero can sometimes be non-associative”: Floating-point arithmetic can be non-associative when rounding occurs, and rounding occurs throughout the domain, not just close to zero.


machine epsilon is the minimum number that, when added to one, gives a non-one result.

Not quite.
machine epsilon is the difference between 1 and the next representable number. ref
